# Modify reference content of an object in swift

Tags: xcode, swift

Given a stackView object, I got an array of `stackView.arrangedSubviews`
which is a get only property. Hence I can't REPLACE one item of it by merely doing

```
stackView.arrangedSubviews[i] = newSubView
```

what came to my mind is I want to replace the content of the reference at `stackView.arrangedSubviews[i]` with the content of newSubView. For instance if this was in C, I would have done something like

```
*arrangedSubViews[i] = *newSubView
```

I know there is a way to do what I need by removing arrangedSubViews and utilizing addArrangedSubView but it won't be very efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify an immutable array, and this is a good thing in many ways.

You can create an extension method to replace the view like this:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
extension UIStackView {
    func replaceView(atIndex index: Int, withView view: UIView) {
        let viewToRemove = arrangedSubviews[index]
        removeArrangedSubview(viewToRemove)
        insertArrangedSubview(view, atIndex: index)
    }
}
```

Then, instead of using `stackView.arrangedSubviews[i] = newSubView` you can use this code:

```
stackView.replaceView(atIndex: i, withView: newSubView)
```

Performance-wise there's no negative impact on doing it this way.

Comment: Thanks for dedicating time to help me. I mentioned that it is a get-only property which means that you can't put `arrangedSubviews` in the left hand side. And BTW it's a mutable array :) .

Comment: @user5526180 see my edit to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: Oohh there's a remove and insert for arranged subviews. I really thank you. Despite I decided not to use it in my code, I chose the "inefficient" way which I wished to avoid :). Because it seems when I use these functions the views I add to the stack view becomes a mess. Swift is really spooky. A lot of times I regret starting with it. Android was better.

Comment: Swift is awesome. Cocoa is sometimes a mess. Android is awesome. Java is horrible.

Comment: You're accurate. I actually started with Swift because it is very appealing and still so. It's cocoa that is annoying. Pisses me off .